# Python 3: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0142' in position 111: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new user of Python.

I'm trying to write script which will help me with sending e-mail messages via my gmail account. Python reads data from .xlsx file and send messages to people from excel list.

Everything is ok until I try to send email with Polish characters.
The same problem occur when Polish characters are used in my excel spreadsheet.

I was trying to use "encoding: utf-8" info, but it is not working.

My code:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
#! python3

# sendDuesReminders.py - Sends emails based on payment status in
spreadsheet.


import openpyxl, smtplib, sys


# Open the spreadsheet and get the latest dues status.

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('duesRecords.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

lastCol = sheet.max_column
latestMonth = sheet.cell(row=1, column=lastCol).value


# Check each member's payment status.

unpaidMembers = {}
for r in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    payment = sheet.cell(row=r, column=lastCol).value
    if payment != 'zaplacone':
        name = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
        lastname = sheet.cell(row=r, column=3).value
        email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=4).value
        school = sheet.cell(row=r, column=6).value
        rate = sheet.cell(row=r, column=7).value
        unpaidMembers[name] = lastname, email, school, rate



# Log in to email account.

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
smtpObj.ehlo()
# smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login('xxx@xxx.com', '')



# Send out reminder emails.
for name, (lastname, email, school, rate) in unpaidMembers.items():
     body = "Subject: %s - przypomnienie o platnosci raty za treningi GIT Parkour. " \
         "\n\nPrzypominamy o uregulowaniu wpłaty za uczestnictwo: %s %s w treningach GIT Parkour w %s." \
         "\n\nWplata dotyczy okresu: %s." \
         "\n\n\nProsimy o uregulowanie platnosci w kwocie %szl na konto:" \
         "\nJESTEM GIT" \
         "\nJ.Klos, M.Kolodziejczyk s.c." \
         "\nul. Grunwaldzka 609d/17, Gdansk" \
         "\nAlior Bank - 36 2490 0005 0000 4500 1296 0191" \
         "\n\n\nPozdrawiamy," \
         "\nGIT Trenerzy."%(latestMonth, name, lastname, school, latestMonth, rate)
    print('Sending email to %s...' % email)
    sendmailStatus = smtpObj.sendmail('xxx@xxx.com', email, body)

    if sendmailStatus != {}:
        print('There was a problem sending email to %s: %s' % (email,
        sendmailStatus))
smtpObj.quit()
```

The error I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sendDuesEmailReminder.py", line 57, in <module>
    sendmailStatus = smtpObj.sendmail('xxx@xxx.com', email, body)
  File "/Users/klos/anaconda/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 854, in  sendmail
    msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0142' in position 111: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329741/issue-with-smtplib-sending-mail-with-unicode-characters-in-python-3-1

Comment: Actually, even better: [how to send utf8 email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910104/python-how-to-send-utf-8-e-mail)

Comment: Read this Answer:. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42825027/openpyxl-convert-cell-value-from-utf-8-to-ascii/42862136?noredirect=1#comment72844689_42862136