# UnicodeEncodeError / python3

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8, ascii

Can't solve typical issue with encodings. Cyrrlic text is received via post and error is raised

```
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The text key itself has a look and it must cyrillic text in russian: u'\u043f\u0440\u043e'

After that error tried this way and some others:

```
  key = key.decode('ascii').encode('utf8')
```

or :

```
key = key.decode('ascii')
```

Localy it works, error is raised in production only. Python system encoding in production is utf8

EDIT: in order to clear things up. Error is raised on form handler function(again, works localy, doesn't in production)

```
def search(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
        key = request.POST.get("key")
        if key is not None:
        ..
```

So it's str received from input form, and error is first raised at this point, so I supposed it must be decoded but it didn't help.

more traceback:

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /search/
```

'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: You would be encoding from unicode `.encode("utf-8")`, I don't see how decode would work anywhere as str objects have no decode in python3, pretty sure you are using python2.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham now I see that you are probably right. Just there is system wide installed python2 in vps, and virtualenv is python3, so I was sure it was using python3, as far as I opened python shell always after activating 'source venv/bin/activate' and 'python manage.py shell' and there python3 is selected

Comment: @PadraicCunningham actually now it's ''str' object has no attribute 'decode'' so yeah it's python 3

Comment: well, I would forget the decode anyway, you have a str already, why are you trying to decode, do you sometimes get bytes?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham well, I added decoding because I was sure it was an issue. Wothout any decoding error is the sams

Comment: How exactly are you getting the error, what is the actual traceback and what exactly are you doing with the str?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it's str from input form, error is first raised on checkpoint whether it's None or not(but no matter). or if decoding before it's raised on decoding line

Comment: The locale is set to utf-8 on the server?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yeah, LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: I do remember something before where the locale settings were different for the server process, I am trying to find the old question/answer here.

Comment: May I see `type(key)` after `... request (`.

Comment: @stovfl class str

Comment: Read this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42825027/openpyxl-convert-cell-value-from-utf-8-to-ascii